# I want my variable should fetch the value in integer format from my database and store it

Tags: python, mysql, discord

```
import discord
import mysql.connector
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all())
mylb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',[![enter image description here][1]][1]
    user='root',
    password="",
    database="worst")
cursor = mylb.cursor()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')
    if message.content.startswith('$howareyou'):
        await message.channel.send('fine')
    a = 0
    if message.content.startswith('$cash'):
        cursor.execute("select cash from mudit")
        
        b = cursor.fetchone()
        await message.channel.send(b[0])
        c = int(b[0])
    if message.content.startswith('$daily'):
        a = a+10
        await message.channel.send(a)
        sql = ("""UPDATE mudit SET cash = (%s) WHERE id = (1)"""%(c+10))
        # sql = "insert into mudit (id,cash) values (%s,%s)"
      
        cursor.execute(sql)
        mylb.commit()
  
client.run('my token')
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'c' where it is not associated with a 
value
```

In this code I want that my variable c should fetch the value in integer format and store it that is present in my database's cash column.I unpacked the list and converted that unpacked value in integer but still my variable c is not storing the value as a literal.

Comment: You assign `c` in the body of one `if` statement and try to use it in the body of another, incompatible `if` statement. How can `message.content` start with `"$cash"` _and also_ with `"$daily"`?

Comment: its a discord bot @Chris

Comment: ...okay? What difference does that make?

Comment: it may start as it these2 will be considered as seprate commands

Comment: and If I wirte $daily so t should add +10 and update my database value

Comment: my basic issue is that the value I fetch from mysql should be stored in integer format in a variable

Comment: That's not how it works, unless `message.content` is some weird object that defines a very unintuitive `startswith()` method. `c` doesn't exist unless `message.content.startswith('$cash')`. If `message.content.startswith('$daily')`, `message.content` _cannot_ start with `'$cash'`, so `c` does not exist (because _`b`_ does not exist, because that code doesn't run). Side note: variables named `b` and `c` are very confusing. I suggest you give them better names.

Comment: sso  pls send me the correct code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250605/discussion-between-mudit-dagar-and-chris).

Comment: pls some one answer

Comment: I _did_ answer: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55732550#55732550 You need to make sure that `c` exists when you try to use it. Exactly how you do that depends on what you are trying to do, but moving your `c = ...` outside of the previous `if` is one option.

Comment: pls someone answer

Comment: Seems like `UPDATE mudit SET cash = cash+10  WHERE id = 1` is sufficient to bump the cash by 10.

Comment: Show us what `message.content` contains at each step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it could be done (note: using global variables like this is not really ideal, but this may at least get you going):

```
import discord
import mysql.connector
...
client = 
mylb = 
cursor = 
c = None    # Declare a global "c".

@client.event
async def on_ready():
...

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    ...
    if message.content.startswith('$cash'):
        ...
        #
        # Write to the global c.
        #
        global c
        c = int(b[0])
    if message.content.startswith('$daily'):
        a = a+10
        await message.channel.send(a)
        #
        # Check that c has previously been set.
        #
        assert c is not None
        sql = ("""UPDATE mudit SET cash = (%s) WHERE id = (1)"""%(c+10))
        # sql = "insert into mudit (id,cash) values (%s,%s)"
      
        cursor.execute(sql)
        mylb.commit()
```

This works because the global declaration of `c` is what is written when the `$cash` event happens, and that global `c` is used when event `$daily` happens. Of course, if your events arrive in an unexpected order, or you get duplicates, or you have multiple threads, etc etc, all kinds of problems can occur. But it should work.

Comment: friend it is showing an error that name c is not defined

Comment: it worked now thanks I just removed assert command